# Lua: Escaping literal % inside string.gsub and the capture %2

Tags: lua, escaping, gsub, lua-patterns

Basic question but I've been trying to figure out for a while with no luck.

I am processing urls and need to do a simple replacement.

I need to replace spaces with the literal string `%20`, but I can't seem to escape the % or the `%2` which is reported as an invalid capture.

```
text = string.gsub(text, "%s+", '%%20')
```

How many `%` do I have to use inside `gsub` to escape the `%` sign and the `%2` capture.

Comment: Are you sure you typed `%%20` and not `%%%20`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems to work for me:

```
> text="hello world"
> print(string.gsub(text, "%s+", '%%20'))
hello%20world   1
```

You'll need to show some more code and your error message.

Comment: My mistake, I was feeding the result of the substitution to string.format() and therefore the % character was bailing me out at that point. Thx for your help. I am leaving the following for reference for this newbie question. http://pgl.yoyo.org/luai/i/string.gsub

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, you can automatically do that with the following:

```
url = require("socket.url")
text = url.escape(string)
```

This is, of course, assuming you do have the socket library in your lua path.  To be quite honest, this is the way I would go about doing anything with urls, because then you don't have to worry about converting commas into %2c or apostrophes into %27.

Comment: oh good information thanks. I would +1 but ran out for the day.